# How could be given two ratios are equivalent?

Tags: ratio

I'm currently learning Maths and got interested in Ratios. Currently, I'm going through equivalent ratio lesson and found that to be magical somehow.

I am impressed that given two ratios can have same value, but I don't know how is it possible and I know the rule and can say whether they are equivalent or not but still I don't understand how it works behind the scenes.

Example

```
Super Salad Dressing is made with 8 mL of oil for every 3 mL of vinegar.
I found that based on rule, 80ml and 30 ml = 8mL and 3mL, if I write it mathematically, 
it would be 80:30 == 8:3
```

If I compare both of them physically, they are not equivalent because 80 Ml larger than 8 Ml and even tho It's amazing that they are equivalent.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $\frac24=\frac48=\frac12$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Your example is clear but I have added real world example to the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Do you have a question? That you don't, would explain the downvote. The rule for equivalence is simple: for integers $a, b, c, d$, $a/b$ and $c/d$ represent the same rational number $\iff a *d = c * b$. Example: $3/8 = 30/80$ because $3 *80 = 30 * 8 = 240$.

Comment: @BrianO I don't care about down votes.  I had a question so asked it.

Comment: Essentially you need to understand the definition of ratio.

Comment: Suppose you have two things and one thing is twice as big as the other.  That's a ratio.  If one thing is $6$ feet and the other is $3$ feet then one is twice as big as the other.  And if one thing is $4$ miles tall and the other is $2$ miles tall then one is twice as big as the other.  That's what ratios *ARE*.  The are the ratio that two items are *in proportion*.  If something is $8$ for the others $3$ it doesn't matter if it's $8$ ml to $3$ ml or if its $8$ metric tons to $3$ metric tons.  The proportions are the same.

Comment: By saying '$80$ mL larger than $8$ mL', you are not comparing the ratios but the quantities themselves. That's probably why you got stuck.

Comment: In your example, if you were to repeat the process of making super salad dressing (which requires you to put 8mL of oil for every 3 mL vinegar) ten times, you would have the ratio of 80 mL : 30 mL.

Comment: The idea is that since you preserved the 8 ml : 3 ml ratio and applied the ratio ten times, it stays equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I compare both of them physically, they are not equivalent

If you compare which physically?

> because 80 Ml larger than 8 Ml

There's no reason to compare the $80$ Ml to the $8$ Ml.   $80$ Ml is $\frac 83$ times bigger than $30$ Ml.  So they are in ratio of $8:3$.  And $8$ Ml is $\frac 83$ times bigger than $3$ Ml.  So they are in ratio of $8:3$. And the Pacific Ocean at $704,000,000$ cubic kilometers is $\frac 83$ times bigger than the Indian Ocean at $264,000,000$ cubic kilometers.  So there are in ration of $8:3$.

A ratio compares the sizes of *two* different things *in proportion* to each other. The absolute size doesn't matter.

If you are trying to compare $80$ ml to $8$ ml they are in $10:1$ proportional.  And that is the same proportion that $30$ ml is to $3$ ml.

If you compare the oil to vinegar there is always $\frac 83$ more oil than vinegar no matter what size your recipe is.

And if you are comparing the two different recipes: the bigger recipe is $10$ times bigger than the smaller recipe.  So the bigg recipe will have $10$ times as much oil, or $10$ times as much vinegar or $10$ times as many eggs, etc.

> and even tho It's amazing that they are equivalent.

Actually it's very dull and mundane and would be very weird if they weren't.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you are correct in the Salad Dressing example that ${80ml}$ is clearly bigger than ${8ml}$, and ${30ml}$ is bigger than ${3ml}$ - however, we are not comparing these numbers directly.

Consider the following example instead - a car travels ${10}$ meters in ${10}$ seconds. Now, it's average speed was then very clearly ${1}$ meter per second. Now, that same car travels ${20}$ meters in ${20}$ seconds - what's it's average speed once again? It's still

$${20\div 20=1\text{ meters per second}}$$

So that same car has travelled a further distance in a longer time - **but at the same speed**. In this case, the "ratio" so to speak is the speed of the car. It's speed has not changed simply because it's travelled a longer distance after a longer amount of time because it's the same speed. The distance to time ratio is ${1 : 1}$. There is only one true ratio.

It's the same story in the Salad Dressing example. The "ratio" is

$${8\div 3}$$

But

$${8\div 3 = 80\div 30}$$

And so indeed ${8:3 = 80:30}$. The ratios are the same, the quantities are not necessarily. I hope this makes it a bit clearer!